# ScrollTop with jQuery and overflow div

Tags: jquery, overflow, scrollto

I'm having a problem, trying to make a `scrollTo` within a div with overflow.

I created five sections and five links in the menu. When I click on a link from the menu, I would like it to be correct div.

The link to content that I did:
http://jsbin.com/adagid/

Sometimes it appears right (when you click directly on the first or last link), but sometimes the content displayed is the middle of the content.

how I can fix this problem?

Comment: He did, actually (the link shows testcase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your code (cloned copy): http://jsbin.com/etexul

Note that you need to take into account current scroll of the container...

```
 var scrollTop = jQuery('#' + gethash).offset().top + jQuery('.content').scrollTop() - 25;
```

25 there due to margin you used on the container

Comment: That definitely does not work. In FF this doesn't scroll elements properly at all.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy just tried that in FF and it does work like it's supposed to (every link scrolls to before the appropriate content block name). what does not work like you expect?

Comment: I can't really explain why it does what it does...but. If you click each link from top to bottom, and then try to click the first link again, it takes about 3-4 clicks, then it scrolls to the 4th item, then back to the first item. It does this for any element after like the 4th click, don't ask me why. FF 13.0.1.

Comment: FF13.0.1 here too and i do not see this behavior here (every single click goes to consistently to its appropriate item)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tested in IE 8/9, Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Since the position of the section changes with each scroll, you want to use `+=` on the property being animated.

Check this fiddle.  I also changed the `bind` to `on` and instead of trying to split the class name to find the section, I used data attributes.

http://jsfiddle.net/KvQ7W/

Answer (score 3):

You need to subtract .contents's scrollTop() to get correct position

http://jsfiddle.net/estevao_lucas/SdUVd/